# Raster layer doesn't project on the fly in some circumstances in QGIS

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis-3, otf

I'm using QGIS 3.16.16 and am finding that when I open a project (my default CRS is 4326) and add a vector layer with a 27700 projection and then add a raster layer with a 4326 projection, the raster does not project on the fly. When I open a project, set the project crs to 27700, add the vector layer and the raster again, the raster projects on the fly. Why is this?
[image]

Comment: why would your raster reproject in the first instance, it is the same projection as the project.

Comment: Sorry my lack of clarity. I can see what's happening with it now, as the projected vector doesn't transform to epsg:4326 when added to the canvas and then somehow changes the project projection to epsg:27700. The raster is then plotted wrongly to a scale of 1:2 in geographic coordinates. See the screenshot below

Answer (score 0):

The vector layer cannot have been projected to epsg:4326. I used 'Set Layer CRS', which transformed the vector layer correctly.